# Solve $\; 0.75^x(x+3)\le0.3 $ (Lambert-W-Function?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, lambert-w

I currently have a problem with solving the following equation: $$0.75^x(x+3)\le0.3$$
It looks like it might be solvable using the Lambert-W function, but the x+3 throws me off. Wolframalpha is able to produce an exact result, so it should be solvable right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply both sides with $0.75^3$, then solve for $x+3$ using [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), and the fact that $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$ .

Comment: Many Thanks :) I've been able to solve the equation to x = -2.86856 and x = 14.0421